# Al montar un sitio existente de worpress en local, solo veo el index y las demás páginas no (linux)

Tags: php, wordpress, web

tengo que modificar un proyecto existente pero cuando intento ver la copia local solo puedo ver la ruta raiz `/` y las demás rutas como `/articles` no las puedo ver, una vea tuve ese problema en laravel pero no sé si será igual la forma de solucionarlo con el archivo .htaccess

Comment: Recuerda que para duplicar un sitio debes cambiar la url en la base de datos y conectarla en el archivo wp-config.php, tambien prueba a resetear el archivo htaccess y en el admin refrescar los permalinks para que se vuelva a generar

Comment: la url es la que está en la tabla wp_options y campo site url, ¿verdad?
no puedo entrar al admin, me redirige al sitio en producción y no me explico porqué

Comment: Si te redirige al sitio en producción es porque aun hay una dirección ahí, dentro de la tabla wp-options cambia la url de site url y home url por tu url local, no uses / al final para evitar problemas con los permalinks, despues reinicia el htaccess al por defecto y carga el sitio de nuevo, si estas en localhost no olvides reiniciar la cache para que no te siga redirigiendo

Comment: entendido, espero me funcione, gracias.